# How to access information about the current Spotfire user through the Spotfire API in a custom extension?

Tags: c#, spotfire

In a custom Spotfire extension - specifically a custom data source or a custom tool, is there any way to access basic information about the currently logged on Spotfire user? A simple user name, user ID, or anything unique to the user would be helpful for what I need to do.

I see there is a property in the Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection class called ConnectedUserName, so the Spotfire user name is accessible there, but that property doesn't exist for a tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` to identify currently logged in Spotfire user.

Comment: That gets you the name of the user that the thread is running as, right? It would work if you are using domain users to log in to Spotfire, but if Spotfire is not set up to use integrated security, I don't think this would match the Spotfire user name.

Comment: Scampbell - I have to verify the integrated security part. But it is not just currently logged in windows user - it is the user you enter at Spitfire login screen, which may differ from your domain user.

Comment: I tried that out and you are correct. I was assuming incorrectly that it would be the windows user that the process is running under, but it is in fact the Spotfire user name. Thanks!